# My prefix will later see you, My infix will tell what's true

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix will later see you.
>
> My suffix will make you calculate.
>
> My infix will tell what's true.
>
> My whole will make you salivate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

*My prefix will later see you.*

> See you = **CU**

*My suffix will make you calculate.*

> **SINE**

*My infix will tell what's true.*

> **I** (stands for a 1, which represents 'true' in Boolean? Or perhaps **IS** - what exists is true?)

*My whole will make you salivate.*

> **CUISINE**

[Another (albeit weaker) possibility:]

> **MEATPIE**. [**Meat** sounds like 'meet' ('will later see you'), **pie** sounds like 'pi' ('will make you calculate'), and **t** could mean 'true' in t\f (true\false) questions.]